# python 3.7 numpy load ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 5218288 into shape (1974,3,128,128,3)

Tags: python, numpy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3dagn.py", line 468, in <module>
    hybrid_network()
  File "3dagn.py", line 107, in hybrid_network
    appx = np.load('file.npy')
  File "/home/dmjeong/anaconda3/envs/fer/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 440, in load
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "/home/dmjeong/anaconda3/envs/fer/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 734, in read_array
    array.shape = shape
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 5218288 into shape (1974,3,128,128,3)
```

Hi, I just wanna load npy file as usual.
but this error occur for the first time.... I have no idea about this error
here's the code

```
appx = np.load('mmi_app_x.npy')
```

other npy files are opened with that code without any error. i don't know 5218288 meaning.
do you have any idea?

Comment: can u share code?

Comment: That it because 1974*3*128*128*3 = 291078144 and not 5218288

Comment: @Aryerez I didn't set 5218288 size. I don't know where it is set.

Comment: @SaiKrishna that's all.

Comment: @SaiKrishna ```import numpy as np``` ```appx = np.load('mmi_app_x.npy')``` and that ValueError occured.

Comment: @damijeong As the file 'mmi_app_x.npy' is not part of a standart `python` installation, but some code file that you have on your computer, there is nothing we can do to help you find the problem without knowing what is the code in that file.

Comment: @Aryerez right. I need to check the code for making that npy file. If I find reason, I'll mention :) thank you for your kind reply.

Comment: `mmi_app_x.npy` looks like a data file created by a `np.save` call.  `np.load` should handle it correctly.  But the reshape expects a data buffer of size 291078144, much larger than the 5218288,  I wonder if the `npy` file has been damaged, possibly truncated.  There's a mismatch between the shape defined in the file's header, and the actual amount of data in the file.

Comment: @hpaulj yes. you are right. i cheked my npy file it has been damaged. thank you for your reply. :) i solve this problem now :)

Answer (score 17):

It probably would be because of a damaged numpy file. In my case the file wasn't transferred correctly between servers. Re-transferring it solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks bro! You saved me a lot of time. :D

Comment: Thanks. For me my external drive was underpowered and had to be plugged in instead of using USB power. Drove me nuts

Answer (score 0):

I reshaped my numpy array to lower dimensions; from (10, 30, 224, 224, 3) to (300, 224, 224, 3). Then I used another `scp` tool, as highlighted by `@ankit shukla`, to transfer `.npy` from high performance cluster (HPC) to my local PC and it worked.