# np.load() in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a set of arrays saved as .npy files and here I am trying to read them all in an add them to a list to concatenate. Problem is, when I try and do it inside a for loop I get "cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (585,1386)" but when I load them one by one they read in just fine... What gives?

'''

```
import numpy as np
import os

arr_list = []

for file in os.listdir('/Users/sjakober/Documents/ResearchSpring2020/geotiffs/'):
    if file.endswith(".npy"):
        arr = np.load(file)
        arr_list.append(arr)
```

'''

Comment: looks like some `.npy` has different shape

Comment: Just a comment that won't fix the error, I believe your source file is located in `'/Users/sjakober/Documents/ResearchSpring2020/geotiffs/'` as Numpy is not throwing the FileNotFoundError, but os.listdir only returns an array with the names inside this path (not the full path for every file). You should append the names inside os.listdir list to the path in order to use numpy load with the full path. I don't think this is going to solve your problem, but will definitely give you code a better look. (also make sure to use os.path.join and not string append)

Comment: @rusito23 is correct. `file` does **not** contain the folder.

Comment: the folder issue may have been it, because I tried using glob and that worked.

Comment: @SarahJakober Great! I'm making an answer for visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when the .npy file is damaged, possibly truncated. There's a mismatch between the shape defined in the file's header, and the actual amount of data in the file. This is stated in a comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58623936/8189455).

The problem in this particular scenario, is that `os.listdir` returns an array with all the **file names** inside the given path, and not the full path to every file. So, when trying to load the array from the `file` variable it may be trying to load a damaged existing file in the current folder, but no the expected one. If the file does not exists, numpy throws `FileNotFoundError`.

This can be fixed by using `os.path.join` and join the filename and the full path, or by using `glob`:

```py
import glob
...
for file in glob.glob("/Users/sjakober/Documents/ResearchSpring2020/geotiffs/*.npy"):
...
```